# Android - auto power up and boot to Home screen

Tags: android

Is it possible for the device with Android to automatically turn on after connecting the power and run to the default laucher without the need for any action by the user?

Let's consider the following scenario.

1. The device lost the power supply, the battery is exhausted and the device has turned off.
2. When the power is back I expect that:
   a. The device turn on.
   b. Boot.
   c. There is no lock screen, any authentication, even simple swipe - completely nothing.
   d. Default launcher runs.
   e. Device is ready for use.

And steps a-e require absolutely no interaction with the user.

If it is required, rooted device is an option.

Question 1 - is it possible?
Question 2 - how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You have to request permission from the user to enable it. Here are the steps you need to take.

First request in the manifest as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then you also need to identify a receiver in the manifest file as follows

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Last you need to create a broadcast receiver class as follows

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);  
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, not working.